# :hover styles don't work

Tags: jquery, css

Got a spinning div. :hover styles don't work on the back side (actually didn't try on the front side). cursor:pointer doesn't work as well. I'm guessing, must be same reason.

A little piece of code

html

```
<div class="newport-view newport-view1" id="blja">view</div>
```

css

```
.newport-back .newport-view {
display: table;
margin:0 auto;
margin-top: 10px;
padding: 3px 6px;
text-align: center;
color: #fff;
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: 700;
text-transform: uppercase;
cursor: pointer !important;
border: 3px solid #fff;
border-radius: 7px;
-webkit-transition: 0.3s;
-moz-transition: 0.3s;
-ms-transition: 0.3s;
-o-transition: 0.3s;
transition: 0.3s;
z-index:6;
}

.newport-back .newport-view:hover {
color: #1D89FC !important;
background-color: #fff !important;
}
```

and a full fiddle here

http://jsfiddle.net/ejtLv49y/

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`backface visibility` is causing issues (notice you can't select the text when it's flipped). If you remove that, it seems to work.

Here's a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ejtLv49y/2/

Basically, I removed:

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden
```

from

```
.newport-item {
    transition: all 1s ease;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    float: left;
}
```

Unfortunately, I'm not sure how this affects mobile devices. I know -webkit-backface-visibility is popular to prevent "flickering". If you're using it for that, you could apply a class that disables that style for desktops only...